# Most efficient way of calling similar query in three places on one page

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008

I've got a PHP page that calls almost the same query three times in the page and wanted to see if there was a quicker way of using this rather than in three seperate instances.

the queries are, in essence

```
select * from dbo.function('foo','bar') 
where userid = $userid 
and status = 'Yes'

select * from dbo.function('foo','bar') 
where userid = $userid 
and status = 'No' 
and value >= 0

select * from dbo.function('foo','bar') 
where userid = $userid 
and status = 'No' 
and value < 0
```

Each time I'm displaying the data in a different table, but wanted to see if there was a more efficient way than querying the database three times.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a function will do the job. something like this will do:

```
function foo($id,$status='No',$value='',$sign=''){
    $value = (string) $value;
    $table = 'table_name';
    $allowedSigns = array('=','>','<','>=','<=');
    $query = "select * from %s where userid = '%s' and status = '%s'";
    if(isset($value) and $value!='' and in_array($sign,$allowedSigns)){
        $query .= " and value %s '%d'";
        $query = sprintf($query,$table,$id,$status,$sign,$value);
    }else{
        $query = sprintf($query,$table,$id,$status);
    }
    return $query;
}
```